# How should I set the language en to get only english results from the PlacesClient by Google in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api

Here are the coordinates I am passing into the emulator:

> Latitude: 25.0783
>
> Longitude: 55.172

Its not giving me the desired results.

Below are the results returned:

> Dubai AE-DU AE - دبي - United Arab Emirates
>
> دبي - الإمارات العربية المتحدة
>
> دبي - الإمارات العربية المتحدة
>
> دبي - الإمارات العربية المتحدة
>
> Ghadeer Venue 1 - دبي - United Arab Emirates
>
> دبي - الإمارات العربية المتحدة
>
> دبي - الإمارات العربية المتحدة
>
> Maeen 1 - دبي - United Arab Emirates
>
> Maeen 1 - دبي - United Arab Emirates
>
> H39 - Yasmin 4 St - دبي - United Arab Emirates

```
val request = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.builder(placeFields).build()
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            placesClient?.findCurrentPlace(request)?.addOnSuccessListener{ placeResponse ->
                if (placeResponse != null) {
                    var i = 0
                    for (place in placeResponse.placeLikelihoods) {

                        //Log.d("PlaceName", place.place.name)
                        //Log.d("PlaceId", place.place.id)
                        //Log.d("PlaceLatLng", "" + place.place.latLng?.latitude + " - " + place.place.latLng?.longitude)
                        Log.d("PlaceAddress", "" + place.place.address)
                        //Log.d("PlaceLikelihood", "" + place.place)

                        if (i == 0) {
                            placeModel.placeId = place.place.id ?: ""
                            placeModel.placeTitle = place.place.name ?: ""
                            placeModel.placeLat = place.place.latLng?.latitude ?: 0.0
                            placeModel.placeLng = place.place.latLng?.longitude ?: 0.0
                            placeModel.placeAddress = place.place.address ?: ""

                            fastSendCurrentLocationToServer(act.applicationContext, placeModel.placeLat.toString(), placeModel.placeLng.toString())

                            initCurrentCityCallGeocodeApi(
                                place.place.latLng?.latitude
                                    ?: 0.0, place.place.latLng?.longitude ?: 0.0
                            )

                            //break
                        }


                        i += 1
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("LocationNull", "" + placeResponse)
                    onCityFetchedListener.onCityError()
                }
            }?.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d("LocationException", "" + exception)
                act.toast("Please enable location services")
                onCityFetchedListener.onCityError()
            }
        }
```